# Blazor isn't passing my object as a Parameter

Tags: blazor

So in my parent component I have:

```
@foreach(var Jewellery in Jewelleries)
{
    <p>@Jewellery?.Name</p>
    <Card Jewellery="@Jewellery"></Card>
}
```

my `<P>` element correctly displays the name, so I know I have all my objects.

When I get into the constructor for my card component Jewellery is always null:

```
[Parameter]
public Jewellery? Jewellery { get; set; }

private readonly string title = "";

public Card()
{
    title = Jewellery?.Name ?? "Empty";
}
```

Have I missed something when passing the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read your parameter inside [`OnParametersSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#after-parameters-are-set-onparameterssetasync)

```
[Parameter]
public Jewellery? Jewellery { get; set; }

private readonly string title = "";

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    title = Jewellery?.Name ?? "Empty";
}
```

Check [ASP.NET Core Razor component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: You can also do: `private string title => Jewellery?.Name ?? "Empty"` which will always get the current value.